# How to let the user make annotation like highlighting, underline or draw in a listview or textview?

Tags: android, listview, draw, highlighting, underline

I'd want know if I can allow to user do some of this in a listview (or defect in a TextView):
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For highlighting, use `BackgroundColorSpan`.For underlining, use `UnderlineSpan`. For drawing, you'll need to come with a custom solution. Perhaps use `StaticLayout` to hold the text, and touch-events to draw in `onDraw(Canvas)` inside a custom `View`. A `StaticLayout` can process spans, so it meets your requirements.

Comment: Sorry my english isn't ver y well. I mean how allow to the user do that?

Comment: `I mean how allow to the user do that?` Yes, my comment tells you how to let the user do that. The implementation will of course need a lot of work. As far as I know, it will be hard to find code/library that meet your requirements in full.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much! I'll look for more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
itemValue = "Your Hilighted Text";
if (itemValue != null) {
    int startPos = itemValue.toLowerCase(Locale.US).indexOf(getTextToFilter().toLowerCase(Locale.US));
    int endPos = startPos + getTextToFilter().length();
    if (startPos != -1) {
        Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(itemValue);
        ColorStateList blueColor = new ColorStateList(new int[][] { new int[] {}}, new int[] { Color.parseColor("#14A4D8") });
        TextAppearanceSpan highlightSpan = new TextAppearanceSpan(null, Typeface.BOLD, -1, blueColor, null);
        spannable.setSpan(highlightSpan, startPos, endPos, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        tvHilight.setText(spannable);
    } else
        tvHilight.setText(itemValue);
    }
}
```